# Do large scale applications use adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am just curious as to how large scale applications like facebook, linkdin, etc model their internal graph data structures. Given the nature of the scale of user base would it be feasible so use an adjacency representation [adjacency list representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) or there exists some other fancy data structures that these tech giants use in graph representation

**edit**
adjacency list as opposed to adjacency list matrix

Comment: While it probably doesn't give an absolutely certain answer, if you look through the docs for Facebook's graph API (for one example) it might well give at least some ideas about what's likely.

Comment: Adjacency matrix? But your link point to adjacency list and it is much more efficient in term of space compare with adjacency matrix.

Comment: Go read how Mahout does their matrix operations by reading the code.

Comment: I can easily google Mahout and find the source but I think it will be helpful if you add a link for the next person who comes across this question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the given use case different approaches can be used to store the graph. For instance in maps the graph algorithms are different from the ones used in friend suggestions in facebook for instance. Still adjacency list is a good solution as it has a small memory usage(in the order of the number of edges) and it can be used to implement a lot of algorithms.